# Tool/application to draw graphs with

Tags: math, graphics

I need to draw a few graphs with data from my application and I'm looking for some easy to use tool that can help me with this. I have about 1000 points per graph that need to be drawn and I can export this data as two arrays (or one, any format really) from my application.

Something that can help me import these arrays easily. Maybe there's something out there that also accepts loops and that would let me generate the samples within the app with a for loop and a function inside it? But that's not a must. If there's some way to easily import the data I'm happy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Octave  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave  . It is open source and although some of the functionality is high end and advanced, simply plotting utilities are quite simple to code. It is free also unlike MATLAB (to which it is VERY similar)

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) is a great tool for this kind of things, but it is expensive.

Comment: To suggest a $1000 tool as a solution to such a novice question seems a bit over the top when there are so many equally good free tools available.

Answer (score 0):

If your graphs should be available on the web, I suggest to have a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). This is a javascript library to make custom graphs. There are different options available on how the data can be inserted, e.g. via JSON or CSV.

Comment: I'm actually already using highcharts, but was looking for a desktop app, I just need a few screenshots for my report.

Comment: Can't you take some screenshots of the highcharts graphs from the webpage? Highcharts also has an exports module that lets you download the charts in different formats: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#exporting

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do and how you want to do it...  Somehow you've got to direct the software into doing what you want.

If you want it all done through spreadsheets and clicking on icons, something like Excel or OpenOffice Calc will work.  They can read in many different data formats and generate common graphics.

If you want to do it via programming, then most programming languages have some way to read in the data and plot it.  Something like Python (the programming language) and Matplotlib (a good plotting library in Python), would work very well, and has lots of examples and is easy to learn.  With this setup you could go from simple to automated to whatever you can imagine pretty easily.